# Changing the content of a Joomla module on homepage

Tags: joomla

I have been asked to make a "one-off" change to the link on the homepage of a website that is running Joomla. The trouble is I am not familiar with Joomla administration. I was hoping it might be similar to WordPress, where I might have to modify a template file, however this does not seem to be the case.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to change the content of a module on the home page of a Joomla site? When I view the module settings in the Joomla admin there does not appear to be any content to edit, just menus and meta data. Thank you.

Comment: I was able to make the changes I needed by gaining access to the template file. I used the Joomla admin interface to do this by going to "Extensions > Template Manager > Click on Template name". There I was able to edit the HTML/PHP of the template file directly.Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every module has its own functionality so it depends on what module you are trying to modify.
You might want to look at [template overrides](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core). By doing a template override you can modify a module output without hacking the core code of the module.

So in the case of a module, you should look into your joomla installation for your module. If your module is called mod_stackoverflow for example, you should look for

```
PATH_TO_JOOMLA/modules/mod_stackoverflow/
```

Next you should look for the template file you want to modify. If you want to modify the default template of the module and if the output of your module can be overriden, you should look for the default.php file like so:

```
PATH_TO_JOOMLA/modules/mod_stackoverflow/tmpl/default.php
```

At this point you should copy the file into your template folder following this structure:

```
TEMPLATE_NAME/html/mod_stackoverflow/default.php
```

By placing this file in your template folder, Joomla will use this file (instead of the one in the module folder) to output the module content. Now you can edit this file as you like.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the assist. This is good information. Unfortunately, I do not have access to the webserver at the moment. A friend who owns the site is trying to switch away from previous developer who is "unresponsive" in making changes. All he has is the CMS login and was hoping I could make the change for him. Might not be able to without web server access.

Comment: you might be able with this [file management component](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/file-management/2630). You can install it from the admin cp in Joomla.

Comment: I was able to gain access to the template via admin interface. See original question for details ...

Comment: the component I  linked above is an ftp client basically...that would allow you to copy the files required to do template overrides. EDIT thinking about it I am not sure if it requires ftp login details...worth a try though.

Answer (score 0):

- Check the homepage content is an article or module . If it was article you just go to the following path.
  Joomla administrator->Contents->Featured Articles->
  here you can find the home page article and modify it by click on article title.

  - If it was module you just go Joomla administrator-> Components->Module Manager
    here you first find which module is enabled in homepage. Then you can edit the module contents.